# Curve : should I use the mean or all values?

Tags: regression, curve-fitting

In my experiments, I measure glycemiae at 7 different times to then draw a curve with R or Excel.

For more precision, I duplicate my measures, so for each time I have 2 glycemiae.

For now, curves data are the means of each time glycemiae, but I tried to enter each single point and R² is not the same.

I'm not sure I'm clear, so here's an example :

> t ---gly1---  gly2
>   -----------------
>  0  ---10   ---12
>  30   ---13   ---15

I can either enter datas (t, gly) as {(0,10), (0,12), (30,13), (30,15)} or as {(0,11), (30,14)}.

In which situation should I use one way or the other ?

Answer (score 1):

$R^2$ will certainly be different if you enter means of replicates instead of all the individual values.

If I were in this position, I'd use the individual values; for example, it allows one to better assess lack of fit and correctness of the variance specification.

In some circumstances other considerations might impact the choice, but in most cases, that's what I'd suggest.

Comment: Yeah, I kinda agree. And when should I use the mean ?

Comment: There may be a number of situations - I can't guess at all the circumstances that might lead to that choice -- but for example if I had really large numbers of replicates (many hundreds say) and many distinct points (enough that I felt I could see lack of fit even just with the means, for example) and were not as concerned about testing, prediction intervals and the like, I might consider using the mean. However, these days it would be a relatively rare situation. It's not like even millions of data points is difficult to deal with.